# iOS development gallery

Tags: ios, gallery, photos

I have an app with a gallery. I have a view full of photos thumbnails. I want to make a view with the photos fullscreen. The problem is that I want to load the fullscreen photos, but when I go back to the thumbnails, I loose all of the information and have to reload it (from JSON). So I think that I've to do it all in the same view controller? Or do you have better solution to me?

Maybe it's a noob question, but I'm new to iOS development (and OOP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Navigation Controller that will help you to switch between the view controller with the thumbnails and another view controller that will be used to show the selected full screen photo.

For more details, read here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html

Comment: hummm and it work's if the view with the thumbs is inside a uitabviewcontroller?

Comment: Sure, when you create the UITableViewController push it on the stack of the UINavigationController